# How do I get a pointer to a property in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, vcl

I'd like a pointer to `TEdit.Text`, but no matter how I express it Delphi insists that `E2036 Variable required`.

Comment: There is no concept of a _pointer to a property_ in Delphi. You may have to try another way to solve your underlying problem.

Answer (score 6):

There is no such thing as a pointer to a property.  Especially a property like `TEdit.Text`, which uses getter/setter methods instead of being backed by a physical variable.

If you need to access a property dynamically, use RTTI for that purpose.

Using RTTI from the older [`System.TypInfo`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/System.TypInfo) unit, you can use [`GetPropInfo()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.TypInfo.GetPropInfo) to get a [`PPropInfo`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.TypInfo.PPropInfo) pointer for the `TEdit.Text` property, and then use the [`GetStrProp()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.TypInfo.GetStrProp) and [`SetStrProp()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.TypInfo.GetStrProp) functions to read/write its value.

```
uses
  ..., TypInfo;

var
  TextProp: PPropInfo;
  S: string;

TextProp := GetPropInfo(Edit1.ClassType, 'Text');
...
S := GetStrProp(Edit1, TextProp);
SetStrProp(Edit1, TextProp, S + ' hello');
```

Alternatively, using enhanced RTTI from the newer [`System.Rtti`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/System.Rtti) unit, you can use [`TRttiContext.GetType()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Rtti.TRttiContext.GetType) to get a [`TRttiType`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Rtti.TRttiType) for `TEdit`, and then use [`TRttiType.GetProperty()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Rtti.TRttiType.GetProperty) to get a [`TRttiProperty`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Rtti.TRttiProperty) for its `Text` property, and then use [`TRttiProperty.GetValue()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Rtti.TRttiProperty.GetValue) and [`TRttiProperty.SetValue()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Rtti.TRttiProperty.SetValue) to read/write its value.

```
uses
  ..., System.Rtti;

var
  Ctx: TRttiContext;
  TextProp: TRttiProperty;
  S: string;

TextProp := Ctx.GetType(Edit1.ClassType).GetProperty('Text');
...
S := TextProp.GetValue(Edit1);
TextProp.SetValue(Edit1, S + ' hello');
```